# Using parameters in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix, parameters

I have a little shell script which goes to a specified Folder and extracts the `.tar` files in that Folder.

Now,I have to use a parameter to change the path to the Folder. 
My first line in my script is `cd /bla/bla/bla` .
I want to read the `/bla/bla/bla` part from a separate file. In that file the first line is `PATH= /bla/bla/bla`.

Anyone got a suggestion for me?

I implemented the solution from Merlin but the script goes into a loop.

My code is:

```
cd head -n 1 PARAM.TXT | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | xargs ./pctrl_ExtractAndRemoveTar.sh;
for file in *.tar.gz; 
  do tmp=${file:34} && b=${tmp%.tar.gz*} && tar tfz "${file}" > "${b}.fl" && tar xzvf "${file}" && rm "${file}"; 
done
```

Big thanks,

Tom

Comment: Using the variable name PATH would probably be confusing, as it already is a variable with a central meaning.

Comment: OK, I could change the name of the Variable.

Comment: You can use: `p="/bla/bla/bla"; cd "$p"`

Comment: I am assuming that `./pctrl_ExtractAndRemoveTar.sh` is the name of your script. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would use a parameter to your script, which I will call `Foo.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash

pushd "$1" 
... Do rest of stuff
popd
```

When you invoke the script, you would say :

```
./Foo.sh my/path/goes/here
```

If you wanted to pull the parameter out of a file, let's say called `Bar.txt`, you could use `head` with `xargs`.

```
head -n 1 Bar.txt | xargs ./Foo.sh
```

Note that the line above assumes that the first line of `Bar.txt` is exactly equal to the path.
If you had the form of `varname=the/path`, you could grab the right part of the assignment using `awk`.

```
head -n 1 Bar.txt | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | xargs ./Foo.sh
```

Update: It appears that the OP is calling his own script in an infinite loop, if I am reading his code correctly. Since you seem to want to hardcode `PARAM.txt` into your script, here is probably what you want.

```
cd `head -n 1 PARAM.TXT | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`
for file in *.tar.gz; 
  do tmp=${file:34} && b=${tmp%.tar.gz*} && tar tfz "${file}" > "${b}.fl" && tar xzvf "${file}" && rm "${file}"; 
done
```

Comment: @tljubas, Please update your question. StackOverflow comments don't support newlines.

Comment: Just did it, sorry! Thank you for the quick answer